# How to only declare a part of a JS module?

Tags: typescript

I can't quite wrap my head around declarations. If I only want to `declare` a part of a module, would this be the correct way to do it (ignoring the use of `any`)?

```
import { Method as JaysonMethod } from 'jayson/promise';
declare class JaysonMethod {
  handler: any;
  execute(server: any, requestParams: any, callback: any) : void;
}
```

If so, what if I want the declaration to be available in other modules that import `Method`? If I have to put the declaration in a `.d.ts` file, would I have to always import `Method` with the alias `JaysonMethod`? How does TypeScript match declarations with the actual modules or parts of them?

I'm just really confused and can't seem to find a good explanation.

Comment: `import { Method as JaysonMethod }...` just rename the named export. You create a variable call JaysonMethod.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you probably confused between the variable and its type.

The line `import { Method as JaysonMethod } 'jayson/promise'` does not declare the type of `Method`, It's a syntax in ES6 to rename the named export.

Something like the following should work:

```
import { Method } from 'jayson/promise';

declare class JaysonMethod { ... }
const typedMethod: JaysonMethod = Method

// typedMethod is now typed.
// or
(Method as JaysonMethod)...
```

Update: Based on your need, it is best to create a typings file instead. Something like:

```
// custom-typings/jayson.d.ts
declare module 'jayson/promise' {
  export class Method { ... }
}
```

And include it in your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "include": [ "custom-typings" ]
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response! I don't understand how your code maps the declaration to the (imported) implementation. You never use the imported `Method` again.

Comment: I have updated the answer. See if it does what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you but this does not compile without errors when I try to create a new instance or extend `typedMethod`. The code in my original question actually does work. I was just wondering how TypeScript matches the declaration with the implementation (when it's in the same file it's seemingly by name) and how I would make this declaration available in other modules.

Comment: If you want to make it available in other modules, do you mean in other files in your project or you re-export the method in your package, or just want to the `jayson/promise` to be typed and used in other packages? Depends on what you need, the solution is different.

Comment: Also, want to clarify that is `Method` a method or a class?

Comment: By other modules I mean other files in my project and `Method` is a class.